# Docker connection Error 127.0.0.1:27018 With MongoDB Docker and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to setup some containers for my NestJS + TypeORM + MongoDB environment by using Docker Compose in a Windows 11 host, but I am getting an ECONNREFUSED error:

```
nestjs-docker-api-1    | [Nest] 1  - 07/23/2022, 8:45:32 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
nestjs-docker-api-1    | MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27018
nestjs-docker-api-1    |     at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:293:38)
nestjs-docker-api-1    |     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
nestjs-docker-api-1    |     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

I have created the following `Dockerfile` to configure the NestJS API container:

```
FROM node:12

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install 

# Bundle app source
COPY . .


EXPOSE 8080

# Creates a "dist" folder with the production build
RUN npm run build

# Start the server using the production build
CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]
```

And then I reference this from Docker Compose with the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  web:
    image: img_1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
      # PORT: 3333
    ports:
      - 3333:3000
    # command: nx serve backend
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
  db:
      image: mongo:latest
      environment:
        - MONGODB_DATABASE="test"
      ports:
        - 27017:27017
```

Finally, I set the TypeORM configuration to match with the Docker Compose file:

```
imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
    type: 'mongodb',
    url : 'mongodb://db:27017/nest',
    entities: [],
    synchronize: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  }),PersonModule,UserModule,
  GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
    driver: ApolloDriver,
    autoSchemaFile: join(process.cwd(), 'src/schema.gql'),
  
  }),],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I tried a lot but the code doesn't work.Any help?

Comment: The error message says there is an error on connecting to `127.0.0.1:27018`. Seems you have a misconfiguration somewhere and you are using `localhost` as address for the db instead of the mongo container ...

Answer (score 1):

From terminal error, it seems that the server is trying to connect with MongoDB server on `127.0.0.1:27018`, while on `docker-compose.yml` you expose/use different port for it

```
db:
  image: mongo:latest
  environment:
    - MONGODB_DATABASE="test"
  ports:
    - 27017:27017
```

However, you can update your connection string in TypeORM configuration in NestJS application to:
`mongodb://db:27017/test`.

last thing, check if your MongoDB server is running correctly from docker using  `docker-compose ps`